# Can't understand this Bootstrap4 display property combination

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap4 for my web application. Now I need to display a menu only when the `lg` (large) screen size is set.

The documentation is very clear: there is a class to hide an element on any screen size:

> .d-none

And there are classes to show an element on a given screen size (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl`):

> .d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-block

My reasoning is that if I want to display an element *only* on a large screen I should use both the classes:

> .d-none .d-lg-block

The first one to hide the element on all sizes and then "raise" only the lg one. But if I look at the documentation it says that in order to achieve this I need to use an extra class, quoting the doc:

[image]

which is extremely confusing. Why the need for the extra `.d-xl-none` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `xl` is bigger screen size than `lg`. If you don't write class `d-xl-none` your block will be visible on bigger screen size than `lg`.

Comment: I see, so basically the "lg" screen size is not a "closed range" of sizes, but instead a right-unbounded range, right?

Comment: `lg` it's all screens whose width is greater than 992px, `xl`  it's all screens whose width is greater than 1200px. If you will write `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none` it means "show my block when screen width greater than 992px and less than 1200px" If wou will write  `d-none d-lg-block` it means "show my block when screen width greater than 992px"